# php, html form passing variables from readir

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla2.5

This is what I'm trying to do, I'm reading directory to display folders on my page, and I display the folders as buttons (type=image) using html `<form>` post method, as you can see the folder names will be read by readdir as `$entry`, everything from reading the directory and displaying it as button image works fine, now i want to be able to pass the `$entry` to the next action i.e lets have an example if `$entry` reads 3 folders:

-glass

-water

-rock

If I click on glass the next page will 'glass'?

Here is my code for index.php/1stpage:

```
<?php
    $entry = readdir($handle);
    $i= -1;
    while($entry != null)

{       $defaultimage = "images/default.jpg";
        if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && $entry != null):?>

            <form name="form2" method="post" action="index.php/next_page">
            <input type="image" name="<?php echo '$entry'?>" 
              id="<?php echo "$entry"?>" title= "<?php echo "$entry"?>" 
              src="<?php echo "$defaultimage"?>" 
              Style=float:top;float:left;width:150px;height:120px;margin:10px;  
              value="submit">
            </form> 

<?php endif;
$i++;
$entry = readdir($handle);}
?>
```

What should I alter in the index.php/1stpage and what should I put in index.php/next_page to be able to pass the folder names?

Comment: I would be very careful doing this. Make sure all your file permissions are airtight. It is a security risk reading a file and outputting it to the screen. People get hacked that way.

Comment: Should I use db or just directory if I am working with photo albums?

Comment: You should use whatever technology is available to you. Reading from the directory is perfectly safe if you do it right. Define a set of directories/files the browser will be able to access, and don't let them access anythign outside of that scope. Also, if you allow a directory, don't put anything sensitive inside that directory.

Answer (score 0):

The action will be

```
 action=<?php echo ("/".$entry  ."")?>
```